OSMDroid: Collision of tiles of the lower layer on the upper one when zooming
I have MapView with base MapOverlay (Open Street Map) and my overlay with Google Hybrid map. When I change the zoom, the screen flashes and the tiles of the base layer blend with the top layer. If I scroll, the tiles of the base layer disappear and everything becomes normal. How can I fix this? I use osmdroid 6.1.20

int alphaI = (int) (p.getAlpha() * 255);
                    setNewView(alphaI, p.getProvider());

private void setNewView(int alpha, String provider) {
        final MapTileProviderArray tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(context) {
            @Override
            public Drawable getMapTile(long pMapTileIndex) {
                Drawable tile = super.getMapTile(pMapTileIndex);
                if (tile != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) tile).getBitmap();
                    Bitmap adjustedBitmap = adjustOpacity(bitmap, alpha);
                    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), adjustedBitmap);
                }
                return tile;
            }
        };
        final ITileSource tileSource = SourceBase.setTileSource(context, provider);
        tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
        final CoreOverlay overlay = new CoreOverlay(tileProvider, context, provider);
        overlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        MV_MAP.getOverlays().add((CoreOverlay) overlay);
        MV_MAP.invalidate();
    }

public class CoreOverlay extends TilesOverlay {
    private String overlayName;
    private int overlayAlpha = 255;

    public CoreOverlay(MapTileProviderBase tileProvider, Context context, String overlayName) {
        super(tileProvider, context);
        this.overlayName = overlayName;
    }

    public String getOverlayName() {
        return overlayName;
    }

    public void setOverlayName(String overlayName) {
        this.overlayName = overlayName;
    }

    public void setAlpha(int overlayAlpha) {
        this.overlayAlpha = overlayAlpha;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAlpha(overlayAlpha);
        canvas.saveLayerAlpha(null, overlayAlpha, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

And zoom code:
MV_MAP.getController().zoomOut();
MV_MAP.invalidate();

I have not found a solution on the internet, and I do not know what to do. invalidate() does not save the situation
